# FLUTTER - DropzoneView: TargetPlatform.windows is not supported appears when hosted in firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-hosting, flutter-web3

I was using flutter_dropzone which supports flutter web application.

When run locally the Flutter Dropzone works normally wherein I can attach file. Please see attachment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVsdG.png)

However, when I finally hosted my flutter webapp to firebase hosting. the dropzone outputs an error "TargetPlatform.windows is not supported". Please see attachment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJozF.png)

commands in deploying to hosting

1. flutter build web
2. firebase deploy --only hosting:<host-name>

pubspec.yaml - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJdfE.png)

Tried searching for related bug, the only thing that I found was that the flutter project was running in windows application.